# Sequential execution of SQL Scripts that depend on the previous script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm probably asking a silly question, but is there a way to execute SQL scripts that depend on each other?

I have a set of 20 scripts, each one is dependent on the table that the previous script creates. Currently it's a case of waiting for each one to finish and without error before setting of the next one. This was fine for a while, but now the total run time is around 15 hours, so it would be really good if i could just set this off over a weekend and leave it without having to keep an eye on things.

Comment: Can't you simply have a script that executes them all, one after one?

Comment: I would consider doing something like that with a C# console app, executing script after script, but dont know the details. 15 hours is a long time! Or maybe a sql job!

Comment: Set it up as an agent job.  You can specific the order of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a stored proc like this.

Create proc SPWaitforTable
@tableName varchar (255)
as
while 1=1
begin
if exists (
select name from sys.tables where name =@tableName)
return
else
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
end

you can run all your script at once, but it will wait until the other table is created to proceed